# Does virtual to physical mapping fixed after disabling ASLR in Linux OS

Tags: linux, gcc, operating-system, virtual-memory, cpu-architecture

I am using gcc in Linux OS. I have disabled ASLR . Now I am getting always same virtual address for the array I have declared as expected.

Now, my questions is, does the virtual to physical address mapping also same during the execution of my program , or , the mapping of virtual to physical address changes during execution of my program?

Any answer/pointer for my question will be highly appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may change if the page with the array is swapped out.

Answer (score 0):

Normally mapping from virtual to physical addresses stay the same during execution with few exceptions. For example, if the page where your array is located becomes a victim to be swapped to a disk, the OS would probably remap it later to another physical address.

But why do you need your array to be pinned in physical memory? You can manipulate physical memory only from the kernel, and if you do something in kernel already you can always perform a pagewalk to get the actual and the most recent translation.

Comment: The processor caches uses virtual and physical addresses. If you know the mapping of virtual to physical addresses, it is easier to predict cache behaviour and performance.